# How to remove registered admin class from menu under Django and xadmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Thanks a lot for your time for reading my questions.

I am using Python 3 / Django 2.0 / xadmin to build my website.
I have 3 models defined in the model file, such as A, B and C.

```
class C(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="TestA")
    product_module = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="TestB")
```

I would like to add A and B from C's add or update page, but I do not want to have specific menus to handle A and B information in the website.

If I register the model as xadmin class it will bring add function in C's page but new menus for A and B at the same time.

Is there anyway to keep add function but remove the menus?

Thanks a lot for your help and wish you a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the way to deal with this.
Adding below configuration before register the admin model :

```
class ClassAAdmin(object):
    hidden_menu = True
```